# how to show Loader on the xaml using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I have integrated usercontrol(Loader) on my xaml page.
I want to show this loader on the fronpage.
if some another pages is loading.

```
  <control:LoadingAnimation  x:Name="ldrControl"  Margin="100,100,100,150"   Visibility="{Binding IsLoaderVisibile}"   />
```

I am able to show this control but when another pages are loading then It's hided.
I have to show this control in front of the pages.

Comment: How do you display *other pages*? To have control *on top* it has to be defined *last* on page.

Comment: Are you loading the pages on the same thread? If so, at what point does the dispatcher set IsLoaderVisible to true?

Comment: yes I am loading the control on same thread.how can I display on same thread.It's  In web apps I have to show back div on front using z-index.

Answer (score 1):

this will work ,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication156"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=Height,
                             Mode=TwoWay}"
             Height="120"
             Background="Transparent"
             IsVisibleChanged="HandleVisibleChanged"
             Opacity="0"
             Visibility="Hidden">
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas Width="120"
                Height="120"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Loaded="HandleLoaded"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                Unloaded="HandleUnloaded">
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="Foreground">
                                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                    <RelativeSource AncestorType="{x:Type local:ProgressBar}" Mode="FindAncestor" />
                                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                            </Binding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Resources>
            <Ellipse x:Name="C0" Opacity="1.0" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C1" Opacity="0.9" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C2" Opacity="0.8" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C3" Opacity="0.7" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C4" Opacity="0.6" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C5" Opacity="0.5" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C6" Opacity="0.4" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C7" Opacity="0.3" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C8" Opacity="0.2" />
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate" Angle="0" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>

public partial class ProgressBar
    {
        #region Public Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// Spinning Speed. Default is 60, that's one rotation per second.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationsPerMinuteProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "RotationsPerMinute",
                typeof(double),
                typeof(ProgressBar),
                new PropertyMetadata(60.0));

        /// <summary>
        /// Startup time in milliseconds, default is a second.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StartupDelayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "StartupDelay",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(ProgressBar),
                new PropertyMetadata(1000));

        #endregion Public Fields

        #region Private Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer for the Animation.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly DispatcherTimer animationTimer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Cursor.
        /// </summary>
        private Cursor originalCursor;

        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Public Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ProgressBar class.
        /// </summary>
        public ProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.animationTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Dispatcher);
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the spinning speed. Default is 60, that's one rotation per second.
        /// </summary>
        public double RotationsPerMinute
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)this.GetValue(RotationsPerMinuteProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(RotationsPerMinuteProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the startup time in milliseconds, default is a second.
        /// </summary>
        public int StartupDelay
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this.GetValue(StartupDelayProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(StartupDelayProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Properties

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply a single rotation transformation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender of the Event: the Animation Timer.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private void HandleAnimationTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SpinnerRotate.Angle = (this.SpinnerRotate.Angle + 36) % 360;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Control was loaded: distribute circles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender of the Event: I wish I knew.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private void HandleLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetPosition(C0, 0.0);
            this.SetPosition(C1, 1.0);
            this.SetPosition(C2, 2.0);
            this.SetPosition(C3, 3.0);
            this.SetPosition(C4, 4.0);
            this.SetPosition(C5, 5.0);
            this.SetPosition(C6, 6.0);
            this.SetPosition(C7, 7.0);
            this.SetPosition(C8, 8.0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Control was unloaded: stop spinning.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private void HandleUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.StopSpinning();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Visibility property was changed: start or stop spinning.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private void HandleVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Don't give the developer a headache.
            ////if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            ////{
            ////    return;
            ////}

            bool isVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (isVisible)
            {
                this.StartDelay();
            }
            else
            {
                this.StopSpinning();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculate position of a circle.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ellipse">The circle.</param>
        /// <param name="sequence">Sequence number of the circle.</param>
        private void SetPosition(Ellipse ellipse, double sequence)
        {
            ellipse.SetValue(
                Canvas.LeftProperty,
                50.0 + (Math.Sin(Math.PI * ((0.2 * sequence) + 1)) * 50.0));

            ellipse.SetValue(
                Canvas.TopProperty,
                50 + (Math.Cos(Math.PI * ((0.2 * sequence) + 1)) * 50.0));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Startup Delay.
        /// </summary>
        private void StartDelay()
        {
            this.originalCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

            // Startup
            this.animationTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, this.StartupDelay);
            this.animationTimer.Tick += this.StartSpinning;
            this.animationTimer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start Spinning.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event Arguments.</param>
        private void StartSpinning(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.animationTimer.Stop();
            this.animationTimer.Tick -= this.StartSpinning;

            // 60 secs per minute, 1000 millisecs per sec, 10 rotations per full circle:
            this.animationTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)(6000 / this.RotationsPerMinute));
            this.animationTimer.Tick += this.HandleAnimationTick;
            this.animationTimer.Start();
            this.Opacity = 1;

            Mouse.OverrideCursor = this.originalCursor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The control became invisible: stop spinning (animation consumes CPU).
        /// </summary>
        private void StopSpinning()
        {
            this.animationTimer.Stop();
            this.animationTimer.Tick -= this.HandleAnimationTick;
            this.Opacity = 0;
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
```

//********************************************

IsLoaded=true; set in Relay Command

IsLoaded =false;

```
 private Visibility isLoaded;

        public Visibility IsLoaded
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isLoaded;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isLoaded = value;
                RasisePropertyChange("IsLoaded");
            }
        }

         <vm:ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="140"
                    Margin="12"
                    Padding="10"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsLoaded}">
        <vm:ProgressBar.Foreground>
            <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" GradientOrigin="0.4,0.4" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DimGray" />
                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </vm:ProgressBar.Foreground>

</vm:ProgressBar>
```

Comment: I am able to show this loader in sample.but  I want to show this using data binding.when realy command fire like this:-  o.IsLoaderVisibile = Visibility.Visible;